# does Avalonia support overlaying views over native ones in web assembly?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

In ControlCatalog sample, there's a page Native Embed where I added a Button **after** the native embedded one:

[image]

But when running, the z-order is not respected:

[image]

I assume Avalonia is not able to respect z-ordering with native views?